# Odoo 12 group_no_one is not working correctly

Tags: odoo-12

I have installed  a version of Odoo 12 via the Debian/Ubuntu package on a server and one version of Odoo 12 running local directly from the source code.

On the test server i can not see fields which are decorated with "group='base.group_no_one', while i can see these options on my local version.

Within both systems all my users are part of the default group "Extras / Technical Features" / "base.group_no_one".

I don't know why this is happening. Since all runs basically on the same code base i expect the views to be rendert the same way on both systems.
Still no data is displayed within the views.
I also get no error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see the fields with the group `base.group_no_one` you need to **activate developer mode** in `"Settings > Activate the developer mode"` *(in the settigns board on the right side).*
Also you can add `?debug=1` to your Odoo URL, for example: http://localhost:8069/web?debug